# How to display files in jquery which are stored outside Server.mappath in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing web page in mvc4 and i want to display pdf files using jquery. I am storing files outside of server.mappath. Below is my controller code.

```
  public ActionResult Download(int? ClientId)
        {
            service.Service objService = new service.Service();
            DashboardBAL objdb = new DashboardBAL();
            string filepath = objdb.GetFilepath(ClientId.GetValueOrDefault(0));
            string folderName = @"F:\UploadedFile";
            //string serverMappath = ("~/UploadedFile");
            string serverMappath = (folderName);
            // byte[] result = objService.DownloadFileFromDMS(filepath);
            byte[] result = objService.DownloadFileFromDMS(folderName);
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath),
                Inline = true,
            };
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(serverMappath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(serverMappath);
            }
            string strdocPath = serverMappath + @"\" + FileName;
            if (result != null)
            {
                FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                objfilestream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
                objfilestream.Close();
            }
            return Json(FileName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I am striing files in @"F:\UploadedFile" which is outside of my root. So it is not directly accessible. In above code i am retrieving filename and corresponding files bytes also. 
Below is  my jquery code to display file.

```
  function ShowFiepopup(FileName) {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Preview of " + FileName,
        width: 850,
        height: 600,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },

        open: function () {
            var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" Zoom=\"100%\" width=\"800px\" height=\"600px\">";
            object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href=\"{FileName}\">here</a>";
            object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
            object += "</object>";
            object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "../UploadedFile/" + FileName);
            $("#dialog").html(object);

        }
    });
};


function Download(pClientid) {

       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: { ClientId: pClientid },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            url: '/TestRendering/Download',
            headers: {
                'VerificationToken': forgeryId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                ShowFiepopup(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

In the jquery i am recieving file name only and below line of code will work only when uploadedfile folder inside my root.

```
    object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "../UploadedFile/" + FileName);
```

But If i store file outside root for example if i save it in @"F:\UploadedFile" path then jquery code will not be having direct access to file. So what is the ways that i can access file and display using above piece of code? I am not sure i want to return just filename or full path? If it is full path then How can i present it in jquery? Please give me some valuable inputs. Thanks

Comment: Is is required for security as well? Let say your upload file is: abc.txt, if I use browser http://www.example.com/UploadedFile/abc.txt , can I access the file?

Comment: If i keep that file inside the root folder i am able to access file. I dont want to access file directly that is the reason i want to keep files in f drive. So nobody can access files directly.

Comment: So how people can download or access it? You can't expect people can access your file just by file name and file path

Comment: Yes. In above code i can get bytes also. So is there any way I can push bytes to jquery and display files?

Comment: If i keep inside the root folder anybody can access files so i want to keep it in F drive. In above code only authenticated users can download files but i am not sure how to present them to those users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an Action inside your controller that returns FileResult and inside this action you will read the file from the F:\ Drive and return it as StreamResult or FileResult, then in your JQuery, instead of writing the file name, you will use the @Url.Actiont to output the URL for the Action that retrieves the file, this way it will always look like it was stored in your wwwroot

```
 function Download(pClientid) {

   $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { ClientId: pClientid },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("actionName","ControllerName")',
        headers: {
            'VerificationToken': forgeryId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ShowFiepopup(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. I am going to try as you said now.

Comment: May i get some usefull link how to use jquery with @url.action especially when dealing with files!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample of how to incldue it inside your jquery function